# How does the HUD prioritize commands?

Tags: hud

Every now and then I want to reach the "Edit > Preferences" menu item in Firefox, and the HUD makes this very convenient.

ALT + "Edi" will suggest exactly that to me. Something that I find annoying however is that if I complete the work "Edit" instead, the HUD will switch to suggest "Network > Edit preferences" instead. While this is a perfectly valid match as well, it seems like an inconsistent behaviour to me.

Could someone explain in more detail how the matching works, so that I can make better use of the HUD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HUD is capable of [Fuzzy Matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_matching) and can learn what you usually do so it can prioritise the things you use often. It covers the focused app as well as system functionality.<sup>[Source](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/939)</sup>

So,in your case if you type <kbd>alt</kbd> and "Edi" and select the Firefox Preferences two or more times,then next time you type <kbd>alt</kbd> and "Edit" you should get Firefox Preferences as first option.

Also if you want to experiment with HUD,you can install command line tools for it.Command line tools are available through the package [indicator-appmenu-tools [image: Install indicator-appmenu-tools]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/indicator-appmenu-tools)

<sup>[Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/HUD#Installing)</sup>